# executeTransaction returns nonce too low error

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I'm trying to execute a safe tx, but it always returns a "nonce to low" error.
This is the code I'm executing:

This first tx works:

```
const tx = await safeSDK.createAddOwnerTx({
        ownerAddress: externalAddress,
      });
      const txResponse = await safeSDK.executeTransaction(tx);
      await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
```

After that, I executed some tx of my smart contract that works perfectly. And after some code, I finally executed this:

```
 nonce = await safeSDK.getNonce();
    const myNonce =nonce+1;
    const gasPrice = "2000000000";
    
   const mintTxData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
      to: myContractAddress,
      data: myEncodedData,
      value: "0x00",
      safeTxGas: "2000000000",
      nonce: myNonce,
      gasPrice: "2000000000"
    };

    const safeTx = await safeSDK.createTransaction({
      safeTransactionData: mintTxData,
    });
    console.log(safeTx); //Here I also check if tx is valid, and it is.
```

And finally I execute this function:

```
    const tx = await safeSDK.executeTransaction(safeTx, options); //Here the tx fails
    await tx.transactionResponse?.wait();
```

The tx fails because supposedly the nonce is too low. I have tried wit the default nonce and adding +100 to `myNonce` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you first need to understand what `nonce` is.

Basically, every transaction done by an account on a blockchain has its `order/nonce`

If I have a private key, and I do a **first-ever** transaction from that account. My `nonce` goes from 0->1. So if I now want to submit a second transaction the **new nonce** has to be set as 1. (In short, nonce is nothing more than the ordering number for the submitted transactions).
If I try **again** to send a transaction with `nonce 0` I will get (Error: "Nonce too low")

Getting the error: "nonce too low" means that the transaction with that nonce had already been submitted and processed by the blockchain. (can't have duplicate nonce for the same private-key).

And if you just randomly increase the `nonce` by **+100** and send it to the blockchain, that transaction will not pass until all the previous `nonce-s` are in the blockchain. Meaning if I sent a transaction with `nonce` 100, I would have to do all the rest 99 `nonce-s` too before the transaction with nonce 100 gets accepted into the blockchain.

What you need to do is get the **current nonce** and use that nonce for your next transaction:

```
const currentNonce = await safeSDK.getNonce();
console.log("Current Nonce:", currentNonce); // Logging for debugging
```

Comment: Hi @sky, thanks for your response.
You are saying what Safe does using the nonce by default (using the current nonce), but I am still getting the same error.
I also tried to specify currentNonce as the nonce, but it still failed.

Comment: When you get current nonce? What do you get? Try first to do it without incrementing the nonce you get, then if that fails, increment it by +1. (See what Error happens then). I am interested in the errors you get for specific scenarios. (It might be good to post errors for different nonces)